# cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have this code:

```
var relatedToQuerySearchParameter = new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter { 
     queries = new String[] { Request.QueryString.ToString() } 
};
```

And when I debug I see this: [image]

So it has a value. But when I try to get this value by doing `Request.QueryString["keyword"]`, as instructed in [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString), I get this error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type QueryString`. Why? What am I missing? It is a REST GET call so there is no view. I just want to pass the keyword with the URL and read it in the controller.

Edit: Ok now I'm lost. Apparently `Request.Query["Keyword"]` works. Would it change? Any idea why the tutorials and posts say to use QueryString?

Comment: That's irrelevant. If you just add an action `methodName(string keyword)` MVC will bind your string to the parameter without you having to touch the querystring

Comment: Liam is correct - you should use binding unless performance is an issue.

Comment: It has changed in AspNetCore.

Comment: yes in Dotnet core you cannot use Request.Query["temp"] instead you use directly create  a parameter in the method which directly pick the query var. for example: if the query string is https://mydomain/2?rate=3 than use parameters like this: function void temp(id, rate)